# HTML Symbol code not working in input field properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My HTML is:

```
<div class="Editable">
    <input type="text" name="Editable" style="width:500px;"/>
</div>
```

I am not able to set value in input field using HTML Symbol code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".Editable").click( function(e) {
        $('.Editable > input').val("&#x0204F; &#x02588; Hello");
    });    
});
```

But setting value directly in the HTML works fine:

```
<div class="Editable">
    <input type="text" name="Editable" value="&#x0204F; &#x02588; Hello" style="width:500px;"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna set directly characters and not htmlentities you can do so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".Editable").click( function(e) {
        $('.Editable > input').val($('.Editable > input').html("&#x0204F; &#x02588; Hello").text());
    });
});
```

### Working Demo